# Why isn't my FontLoader running in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple webapp I have created using a three-js boilerplate. I am able to add other geometries to the scene and see them rendered, but when I tried to add a textgeometry via Fontloader, nothing in the 'loader.load' function gets called, even the console.log messages. I'm sure the issue is related to being unable to find the file or something similar, as if I supply a URL it works properly, but that approach wouldn't allow me to use a custom font as I want.

```
  loader.load("fonts/sheandy_Regular.json", (font) => {
    console.log("entering font loader")
    var dummy = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: '0x00b294',wireframe:'true'})
    obj = new TextGeometry("AT", {

      font: font,
      size: 20,
      height: 5,
      curveSegments: 1,
      bevelEnabled: false
    });
    
    console.log(font)
    text = new THREE.Mesh( obj, dummy );
    text.position.x = 0;
    text.position.y = 0;
    text.position.z = 0;
    // text.rotation.y = 13
    scene.add(text)
    render(); // Only added this render for debug purposes, nothing in the load gets called
  })
```

My directory structure is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeFbb.png)

Tried to use the loader.load function after creating a `const loader = new FontLoader()` but no code in the loader.load function actually gets ran when I supply a local file path for the font json.

UPDATE: After continuing to test, I see that it's because the folder I have the imported font in is not included in the webpack configuration. However, I'm not sure how to adjust which folders get included in the export so any advice there would be helpful.